# Free will theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Can somebody indicate a proof of the [free will theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_theorem) based on the singlet state of two spin 1 particles,

$$\lvert S_b\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \left( \lvert 1\rangle \lvert -1\rangle - \lvert 0\rangle \lvert 0\rangle + \lvert -1\rangle \lvert 1\rangle \right)$$

I would be very glad for a reference. Please don't tell me to search for articles or books, because I did it. I don't see this state in either articles about the free will theorem, nor in articles about contextuality.

It's the state that interests me, and if it can be used for the above purpose, not other proofs of the theorem. It seems to me that it was used but I don't know by which authors.

Comment: I'm curious about your creation of the tag [tag:contextuality]. Contextualism is a philosophical set of views, not a physics topic. I don't think it's an appropriate tag here

Comment: @Jim : the definition of a contextual experiment is as follows: given 3 operators, A, B, C, s.t. A commutes with B and with C, but B and C don't commute, in a measurement of A together with B, A may give another result then if A is measured with C.

Comment: Okay, I'm just hesitant to create so many new tags at once. I won't argue the free will theorem tag, but contextuality sounds like it might not be as useful as you'd think in terms of being a tag

Comment: Contextuality is a very big topic in quantum theory, if you'll learn this issue you'll see.